# Getting data from strage construction (Cheerio)

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

```
<div class="testClass">
<strong>Num1</strong> 
: 16X
<br>
<strong>Num2</strong> 
: 16X
<br>
<strong>Num3</strong>
 : 12X
<br>
<strong>Num4</strong>
 : 12X
<br>
```

I need to get "Num1" ect, as well as ":16x" ect. 
But how can I get ": 16x" I don't know,it's not betweentags, or something.

I'm doing it using node.js with cheerio. It's a web scraper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't find anything in Cheerio that would do it out of the box, so I hacked this:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const html = `<div class="testClass">
<strong>Num1</strong>
: 16X
<br>
<strong>Num2</strong>
: 16X
<br>
<strong>Num3</strong>
 : 12X
<br>
<strong>Num4</strong>
 : 12X
<br>
</div>`;


const $ = cheerio.load(html);

let num, val;
const results = [];

$('.testClass').contents().map((i, el) => {
    // console.log(i, i % 4, $(el).text().trim());

    if (i % 4 === 1)
        num = $(el).text().trim();
    if (i % 4 === 2)
        val = $(el).text().trim().match(/: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/)[1];
    if (i % 4 === 3)
        results.push({ [num]: val });
});

console.log(results);
```

The results of the `$('.testClass').contents()` (from the commented out console.log) is:

```
0 0 ''
1 1 'Num1'
2 2 ': 16X'
3 3 ''
4 0 ''
5 1 'Num2'
6 2 ': 16X'
7 3 ''
8 0 ''
9 1 'Num3'
10 2 ': 12X'
11 3 ''
12 0 ''
13 1 'Num4'
14 2 ': 12X'
15 3 ''
16 0 ''
```

Using the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder_()) and some regex, we're able to extract the values you're after:

```
[
    { Num1: '16X' },
    { Num2: '16X' },
    { Num3: '12X' },
    { Num4: '12X' }
]
```